# No module named datagen even though I imported it

Tags: google-colaboratory

I came across this error "No module named datagen" even though I imported datagen using !pip install datagen.

Here is my code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkVfp.png)

Here are the errors:[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7bty.png)

Any ideas why this is happening? Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because PIP failed to install *datagen* (source: tried it myself)
It's better to separate `!pip install ..`  statments from your python code, collect those to the separate cell or each into its own cell. This way you'll have better overview of installation status and errors.